# Simple way to write set of elements that are in either set but not both

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Consider two sets $P$ and $P$'. I am trying to find the simplest notation denoting all elements that are in either $P$ or $P'$ but not both. I think this is $(P\cup P')\setminus (P\cap P')$. Is there any symbol in set notation already reserved for this operation?

Comment: Called symmetric difference 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: That is correct, as is $(P\cap\overline{P'})\cup(\overline P\cap P')$ (where $\overline P$ denotes the complement of $P$), as well as $(P\setminus P')\cup(P'\setminus P)$ (where $\setminus$ denotes relative complement).

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the [*Symmetric Difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of two sets:  $$P \triangle P'= \{x\mid (x \in P \lor x \in P') \land x \notin (P \cap P')\}$$

What you wrote is also, essentially, a definition of the symmetric difference of $P, P'$: $$P\triangle P' = (P\cup P')\setminus (P \cap P')$$

---

Note: sometimes $P\oplus P'$ is used to denote the symmetric difference of sets $P,P′$; however, this notation is used frequently in the context of boolean logic; $\oplus$ is used to denote the "exclusive or", between two propositions,  e.g. $$p⊕q=(p∨q)∧¬(p∧q)$$ which means "either p holds, or else q holds, but it is never the case that $p \land q$." holds.

Comment: I would prefer an Equals sign to a Colon................+1

Comment: Hi!!  Sure, @mrs

Comment: @amWhy: How can I make another Gold badges?

Comment: Have you ever earned a gold badge through the review queues?  Just at 20 reviews per day in the close vote review, voting to close or keep open, or skip, for 50 days earns you a gold badge (for a reaching 1000 reviews).  Also, suggested edit reviews, are pretty available.  You can earn a gold badge per review type.

Comment: @amWhy: Yes I've got. I mean what does that `970  group-theory x425` mean under the Tags in my profile? Does it mean if it reach 1000, then I will be given a gold medal. :-))

Comment: @mrs: There are also gold badges available for reaching a certain number of edits of posts, which is separate from the review queues, which you can work at over time to meet.  I'll try and review the badges again, to check for other ideas, too!

Comment: @mrs:  Oh, that's good news.  It means you need only 30 more group-theory upvotes, and already have the necessary "minimum spread over 400 group theory answers".  So thirty more upvotes on current group theory answers, and/or, answer a few more to earn the 30 remaining.  When you hit 1000 group theory upvotes, earned with a minimum of 400 answers in group theory, you've got your gold!!

Comment: You need only 40 more upvotes in calculus, and you'll get a gold star in calculus.

Comment: @amWhy: Thankls for your time. You have helped me mentally here. I owed to you dear friend.

Comment: I miss you; I just figured out you changed your name recently, else I would have commented back to you yesterday, or when you last commented!  I like your profile picture very much!

Comment: @amWhy: Miss you too...

Comment: Have a loook at this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwitgqSSua3dAhXLZlAKHdBTBtAQFjAFegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2FHow-have-you-used-math-stack-exchange-to-learn-mathematics&usg=AOvVaw3lPVxX6ItTQnXxgZcTWEmt). search your name ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Along with what the other person said, in Boolean Algebra this is an XOR and is denoted by

$$
A \oplus B
$$